Disabling Fail-Fast on Workflow Call
I'm building a reusable GitHub Actions CI process using one workflow which runs on code changes, named ci.yml, and a handful of other workflows rust.yml/node.yml/docker.yml. Here is an example of the hierarchy:

ci.yml

rust.yml jobs:

build
test
audit


node.yml jobs:

build
test
audit





Here's a rough example of ci.yml:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  rust:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/rust.yml
  node:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/node.yml

And here is node.yml:
on:
  workflow_call: {}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: sleep 60

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: sleep 30 && exit 1

  audit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: sleep 90

And here's what I observe:

As can be observed, if any job within node.yml fails, it cancels all other pending jobs in that workflow. If I instead hoist all of these jobs directly into ci.yml, any failing job won't cancel all the other jobs, they will be allowed to complete, even though the run will fail. This is the desired functionality, I'd like to know the outcome of all of the root-level jobs being run. Canceling the build job immediately when test fails is unhelpful, I'd like to see if build fails as well.
I can't seem to locate a fail-fast option for workflow_call.
How can I replicate the functionality in a root workflow in my workflow_call workflows?
Observed behavior:

if any job within node.yml fails, all other jobs in that workflow are cancelled immediately.

Desired behavior:

if any job within node.yml fails, the jobs which have already been started should run to completion so I can see if any of these steps are also failing.


This was my error: since node.yml is being called with a matrix, I failed to specify fail-fast: false on it. The fix for ci.yml is:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  rust:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/rust.yml
  node:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/node.yml
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        job:
          service:
            - service-a
            - service-b

For some reason, I didn't think this through at the time, but in hindsight it should have been clear.
